# Java.nio fails to write to directory that executing user actually has write permission to

Tags: java, nio, java.nio.file

Sorry folks, completely irrelevant question since the mistake was somewhere else.

Comment: Can you show the output of "ls -l" (are you sure you have the right permissions?) as well as the code?

Comment: Can you also post the entire StackTrace?

Comment: I have provided more info now (code, permissions on directory and stacktrace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the directory: you need to have the execute bit set for your user in order to be able to access the directory and to read/write files within.